# Why are my marks not drawn?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm somewhat stumped by the following simple plot at the moment.  I expected three black marks to be drawn.  Instead, I see no points being drawn (only the axes).  This is based on old code, so I'm quite sure it worked before:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[only marks]
\addplot[black] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why am I not seeing any points plotted, and how should I alter my code so I will?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `only marks` to the `\addplot` not to the axis.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot[black,only marks] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aah.  Did this perhaps accidentally work in older `pgfplots` versions?

Comment: @gerrit No way! :-) It is a plot specific characteristic not axis specific.

Comment: Strange.  I copied over code from my thesis (`pgfplots` version 1.8) and I certainly have the markers there in my thesis.  Ah well, I got it to work now :)

Comment: @gerrit You can put `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` and then too it won't work :-)

Comment: I suppose `compat=1.8` does not extend to things that *should* not have worked in the first place, but accidentally did due to bugs...